# Import specific section from another tex file

Tags: latex

I'm trying to import a very specific section or subsection from another **latex document**.
 I basically have an export tool that creates a nice tex document and makes the sections for the headers. It's nice to call the whole file but at some point in my combined document I have to just call a subsection over and over again.

**How do I call a specific subsection from a whole document?**

I have a file call `aa.tex` and I'm able to use `\subimport{}{aa}` and it brings in the whole file.

In the file it look similar to

```latex
\section{Test Descriptions}
\subsection{Setup}
Hardware and Software... CPU, GPU, RAM etc
\subsection{test1}
\subsubsection{Steps1}
a,b,c,
\subsubsection{Steps2}
a,b,c
```

I want to be able to call `\subsection{setup}` over and over again because of what I have to reference.

So, logically how do I only call `\subsection{Setup}` from `aa.tex`?

Comment: The simpler is to put the section is a separate file and to \input it from whatever file it is required, including aa.

Answer (score 4):

With the `catchfilebetweentags` package one can selectivity input parts of a file

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

zzz

\ExecuteMetaData[subdocument]{setup}

zzz

\ExecuteMetaData[subdocument]{setup}

\end{document}
```

subdocument.tex:

```
xxx

%<*setup>

\subsection{Setup}

%</setup>

xxx
```